# Automating Video Editing in the Cloud

Tags: automation

I have a few classes that I teach over Zoom that I need to edit every week. The edits are very simple: trim the beginning of the video and add an animation of our logo at the beginning. Basically, trim 2 minutes, and add another video at the beginning.

Any ideas if there is a website that can do this automatically, or at least automates part of the process in the cloud? It only takes me about 20 minutes per video but it is very tedious and the rendering takes hours.